# Cannot open Azure VM open port

Tags: azure, port, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I have a development computer game server which is running on a Azure VM.
At the moment i'm unable to see a service running via the port(22) on the VM. I have added an inbound rule on the Networking settings for the VM on Azure as seen in the image

***Azure Portal***
[Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUWZP.png)

I have also added an inbound rule in the firewall on the VM itself as seen below for those ports. ( There is another rule for TCP that has the same configuration)

***Firewall Settings***
[Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfevb.png)

As seen in the image below, the program is listening to one of the ports, but using http://canyouseeme.org/ (as seen on the left side of the screenshot below) the port doesn't seem to be open.The right side show the Application(server) listening to the port(22).

***Program***
[Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euh7J.png)

Is there something that i'm not configuring correctly? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am a bit confused, does your sever VM have a sudden connection timeout? and what is the meaning of "the server and visual studio will put a strain on any computer. "?

Comment: Hi Nancy, The VM doesn't suddenly time out when i remote to it. But it does timeout when i try accessing the port (22).  "running the game, the server and visual studio will put a strain on any computer." Was additional information as to why i require a VM for those who might suggest running the game server locally. I have now edited this to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, From the screenshot of your firewall setting in VM, you should configure the **specific ports 22,43** as **local port**; configure **All ports** as **remote port** for an inbound firewall rule in VM.

Secondly, i have tested the port status in my VM using http://canyouseeme.org/. As a result, for TCP port, it works well, but for UDP port, it could not reflect the port real status even I have configured the firewall settings and portal NSG. The reason should be that UDP protocol is not the same as TCP protocol which has the three-way handshaking connection.

In conclusion, we could use this method to check TCP port; for UDP port, we need to verify it by accessing that service or application directly from client.

Comment: Thanks, making the ports local instead of remote worked. My application was able to access the game server though as you mentioned http://canyouseeme.org/ wasn't showing the port as working.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure these ports as local ports and that should allow the app to access on UDP